# Android service interactions

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, binding, android-service

I have a list of tasks that are displayed inside a RecyclerView. 
For each task I present an activity containing:

- A play button that displays a chronometer when clicked
- A done button to say a task is complete and to stop the service bound to the activity.
- Various information

The user can stop a task to resume it later and launch various tasks at the same time.

I need to implement a Service to keep each chronometer running in the background during the lifetime of a task.

I followed the guidelines here : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

How can I create a unique service per task and display the chronometer back (with the elapsed time) when a previous task is selected by the user.
What is the proper way to update an Activity second by second ?

```
public class TaskService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "TASK SERVICE";

    public static final String ACTION_TIMER = TaskService.class.getName() + "TIMER";

    private IBinder mBinderTask = new TimerTaskBinder();

    private Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommande: ");

        mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);
        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        mChronometer.start();

        return START_STICKY; // Will be explicity started and stopped
    }


    public String getTimestamp() {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        int hours = (int) (elapsedMillis / 3600000);
        int minutes = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
        int seconds = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;
        int millis = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000 - seconds * 1000);
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + millis;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return mBinderTask;
    }

    public class TimerTaskBinder extends Binder {
        public TaskService getService() {
            return TaskService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a service just to keep track of a timer. I would suggest storing the start time and the expected stop time of your task using [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()), and just setting the chronometer with the calculated time remaining every time the recyclerview becomes visible.

Comment: I'm planing to collect other data like user location and movements when I understand how to interact with a service

Comment: When you say movement, do you mean user activity (walking, driving, etc.)?

Comment: Yes GPS monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a `Service` per task. Just create one `Service` and have it manage a list of tasks.

To communicate between the `Service` and the `Activity` you have multiple choices:

- Use `BroadcastReceiver`. Your `Activity` creates a `BroadcastReceiver` and listens for broadcasts that are sent at intervals by your `Service`. The `Service` calls `sendBroadcast()` to broadcast events of interest. Hint: If your `Activity` and `Service` are running in the same OS process, you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` (it is a bit more efficient).
- Use a bound `Service`. Bind your `Activity` to the `Service` and the `Service` can call back methods in the `Activity` as necessary.
- Use an "Event Bus" implementation like Green Robot's `EventBus` library.